# Most likely topological order given distance matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, linear-algebra, distance

Given:

- a distance matrix (`n x n`) between `n` discrete points in 3-D space ( eg. n = 5 // `points = [x_a, x_b, x_c, x_d, x_e]`)
- the expected interval `d_ij` between adjacent points (`d_23 = dist(a_2 - a_3)`)

Is there a performant algorithm to estimate ***the most likely*** ****topological ordering**** of the points (`eg. top_order = [x_b, x_c, x_e, x_d, x_a]`)?

I realize there is no ***unique*** solution, but, the key is estimating the most likely ordering, using the expected adjacent distances as an expected value and modeling the order probabilistically. I'm sure this is a solved linear algebra problem, but I just don't have the exact vocabulary to find it. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by topological ordering? The normal use of this term has nothing to do with metrics.

Comment: Yes, I realize it sounds strange but I mean it in its traditional, graph sense: For n = 5, I wish to find a path through all 5 points such that the distance traveled between each point best matches a set of 4 expected distances (d12, d23, d34, d45). The difficulty is in identifying which of the points [x_a, x_b, x_c, x_d, x_e] should be picked *first* in the topological order; which second, third... and so on

Comment: This looks very much like a traveling salesman problem to me.

Comment: TSP is a broad class. Can you be more specific? Thank you.

Comment: TSP is not a broad class. Given a graph, find the shortest Hamiltonian path/cycle.

Comment: Wait I probably misunderstood the problem. The expected distances are all different, right? Then this doesn't map to TSP well.

Comment: Yes, the expected distances are different. 
No, TSP is a broad class (classical, time-dependent, symmetric v. asymmetric).

Comment: I meant classical. You can map this onto the classical TSP but of a higher dimension (n^2 points) so this is not really feasible. This in fact might map to a time dependent TSP better, but I'm not familiar with this variety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, I realized this is called the **Molecular Distance Geometry Problem**. There appears to be interesting quantum algorithms that can solve this very quickly.

A review can be found here: [https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/mdgp_encopt2.pdf](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Eliberti/mdgp_encopt2.pdf)

Comment: Doesn't look like DGP to me at all. In DGP you have distances and need to find coordinates. There is no notion of order there.

Comment: I would argue the discovery of coordinates has an additional dimension - if it were in 3-D, the 4th dimension is the order. Here we have the distances between molecules and we also have (candidate) coordinates - but we don't know which one to "pick" in terms of order. Is this clear, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I have no idea where, given the paper, you get the ordering from. This is not what the paper purports to find.